# React js filter is not working but the search fileld is coming

Tags: reactjs

```
  render(){
    const { users, isPending, usersearch='' } = this.props;
    const filteredUsers = users.filter(user => {
      if(!user.name == undefined){
        return user.email.toLowerCase().includes(usersearch.toLowerCase());
      }
    })  
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
        {
          isPending ? <h1>Loading</h1> :
          filteredUsers.map((user,id) => {
                return (
                  <div key={id}>
                  {
                    user.name ?
                    (
                      <div className="card">
                        {user.email}
                      </div>  
                    ):(
                      ''
                    )
                  }
                  </div>

                )
            })
        }  
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here i am trying to search in react using filter()
but it is always giving me empty result But i can see usersearch  by logging in my console.

Please have a look

Comment: `!user.name` is never `undefined`.

Comment: Issue was in backend data. I fixed it